# Programmatically adding glyphs (delete key, backspace, space, etc) to menu item

Tags: cocoa, macos, menu, nsmenuitem, glyph

It used to be that in Carbon you could use SetMenuItemKeyGlyph. What's the alternative under 10.6? Will I need to use undocumented goodness or...?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `-[NSMenuItem setKeyEquivalent:]` and give it an `NSString` of the character you want to be used.  `NSMenuItem` will handle translating `@" "` into `Space` for you, etc.

Delete key (aka "Backspace". This is the regular delete button on your keyboard):

```
[myMenuItem setKeyEquivalent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", 0x08]];
```

Forward delete key (The "del" key):

```
[myMenuItem setKeyEquivalent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", 0x7f]];
```

Space:

```
[myMenuItem setKeyEquivalent:@" "];
```

Tab:

```
[myMenuItem setKeyEquivalent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", 0x09]];
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Would you know where I can pull up the codes for the eject, escape, and cursor arrow keys?

Thanks

Comment: Not all glyph codes in Menus.h will work since Cocoa bit shifts some of them, including the arrow keys. There are enums for these in Cocoa.    NSUpArrowFunctionKey = 0xF700,
   NSDownArrowFunctionKey = 0xF701,
   NSLeftArrowFunctionKey = 0xF702,
   NSRightArrowFunctionKey = 0xF703

Comment: You can also use constants instead of the character codes directly, for example `NSBackspaceCharacter` instead of `0x08`. See Apple's [NSText reference document](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSText_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000367-20750) for a list of constants.

Comment: Swift: keyEquivalent = NSString(format: "%c",NSBackspaceCharacter) as String